# Elasticsearch: disable coordination factor for multi match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I use a multi match query with different weights on each field.
I set tie_breaker to 1 to disable use_dis_max and use the sum instead of the max for the score.

```
GET index_name/index_type/_search?explain
{
 "size": 1,
  "query": {
  "multi_match": {
   "query": "ticket",
   "fields": ["title^9", "descr^4", "*section_body"],
   "tie_breaker": 1
  }
 }
}
```

ES sums the scores for each field then multiplies it by the coordination factor.

I want to disable the coordination factor, so I tried to wrap my multi match query into a bool query and set disable_coord to true as the following:

```
GET index_name/index_type/_search?explain
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "disable_coord": true,
       "should": [
         {
          "multi_match": {
          "query": "ticket",
          "fields": ["title^9", "descr^4", "*section_body"],
          "tie_breaker": 1
           }
         }
      ]
    }
 }
}
```

But I can see that nothing changed in the scoring formula, ES is still summing the scores for all different fields then multiplying the result by the coordination factor.

How can I disable the coordination factor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommending separating the individual conditions of the `should` and boosting them individually.  That might look something like the following:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "disable_coord": true,
      "should": [
        {"match" : {"title" : {"query" : "ticket", "boost" : 9}}},
        {"match" : {"descr" : {"query" : "ticket", "boost" : 4}}},
        {"multi_match" : {
          "fields" : ["*section_body"],
          "query" : "ticket"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For a silly set of test data I ginned up, it does look like this results in the coordination factor no longer being applied, namely that the resulting scores for each document are higher when `disable_coord` is `true` versus when it is set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal is to give less weight possible to all "*section_body" fields and your solution does that.
However, one of my search scenarios is "all words match". In this case I use mutimatch query with type set to  "best_fields" and  operator set to "AND".

Can I apply the same logic for this case and separate my multi match query into a list of match queries ?

Comment: It should work in that case as well.  Underneath the covers the `multi_match` query will be executed as a collection of field-specific `match` queries anyway - it's just that the `multi_match` form seems to abstract away the ability to disable coordination.  If that is your goal, you will have to straight to the decomposed form (multiple `match` queries).  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html